# Iterate ElementRef in Angular2

Tags: angular

I'm using ElementRef to get the DOM object of Component. Using **elementRef["nativeElement"]** I got something like this-

```
<selectorName>
  <input type="text" />
  ......
</selectorName>
```

I want to iterate the all Html object to get the element type and id. Can any one suggest me how to do this.

Comment: Please provide more context. Why do you want to do that. Where does the HTML come from? Where do you have that code that used the `ElementRef`.

Comment: I have defined the ElementRef inside constructor. I am using API to generate the UI form which required the Html object, So I want to iterate the html object and pass it to API.

Comment: Please add more code that demonstrates all that.

Comment: Actually I am using metawidget API to create UI form from json schema, metawidget API required html object, to rendered the UI. So I'm trying to iterate the html object and pass it to metawidget API.

Answer (score 5):

```
constructor(private elRef:ElementRef) {}

ngAfterViewInit() {
  let elements = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelectorAll('someSelector');
}
```